# There is no doBy package for R-4.0.1?

Tags: package, r-4.0

I've started working in the R-4.0.1
The *doBy* package doesn't exist. 
Anyone know a workaround to this? 
NOTE: I am really just interested in the summaryBy command.

Comment: The package does exist on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doBy/index.html. Why do you think it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

On my side, no matter how hard I tried I got this message in Rstudio:

```
> library(doBy)
Error in library(doBy) : no package named 'doBy' is found
```

The "classic" installation command did not work for me. When I tried to find it via RGui or RStudio, it didn't appear either.

1. I updated my R version (from RGui)
2. I reopened RGui, install my package, there, when I searched for doBy, it appeared in the list of packages.
3. After this installation (and loading) on RGui, I opened Rtudio in administrator mode and retried the command :

   install.packages("doBy", dependencies = TRUE)

And, it FINALLY worked.
Edit : i have the same issue with other package, and this solution works for many case.